# Is there a way to read the monitoring_role_arn from RDS into terraform.tfvars?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-rds

Instead of having to update this value manually each time, can I read this value directly into my terraform.tfvars file?
`monitoring_role_arn = "arn:aws:iam::account:role/value"`

Comment: `.tfvars` file can only contain static values as it's a variable file. But you can use `data` resource to read it from any of the `.tf` files. You can use the `.tfvars` to provide the static values used to filter the `data` resource tho.

Comment: @PraveenPremaratne is there an example that you can share?

Comment: I can provide a tailored code if you post a sample code. I've added a generic answer to Abhishek's already existing answer.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [locals](https://www.terraform.io/language/values/locals#:%7E:text=Declaring%20a%20Local%20Value)

Define in *.tf file

```
locals {
  monitoring_role_arn = "arn:aws:iam::account:role/value"  
}
```

in variables file you can refer as below

```
your_var = local.monitoring_role_arn
```

### Role lookup option

Alternatively use the IAM Role lookup by the name given to the targeted role.

Ref: [Data Source: aws_iam_role](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/data-sources/iam_role)

*To looup the resource by role name:*

```
data "aws_iam_role" "monitoring_role_arn" {
  name = "an_example_role_name" // This is the name of the role that appear in the AWS IAM Console
}
```

*To get the ARN use the following line:*

```
data.aws_iam_role.monitoring_role_arn.arn
```

Comment: But if the monitoring_role_arn is something that changes often, how can I read it?